# Scala ReactiveMongo: Channel not found on minor internet outage

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Reactive Mongo stops on minor internet outage and doesn't restore, neither play stops, just subsequent queries get these repeated exception saying connection 10/1 but channel not found.

This is mentioned as GitHub issue as well, but no solution is given. what I want to know is that is there anyway using which I can monitor connection  health and restart server in case of network outages or reactive Mongo's failure to access the DB server

Exception given by application:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ChannelNotFound: MongoError['Channel not found from the primary node: 'ds249005.mlab.com:49005' { authenticated:0, connected:10, channels:10 } (Supervisor-1/Connection-2)']]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180)
    at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:122)
    at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:120)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
Caused by: reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$ChannelNotFound: MongoError['Channel not found from the primary node: 'ds249005.mlab.com:49005' { authenticated:0, connected:10, channels:10 } (Supervisor-1/Connection-2)']
Caused by: reactivemongo.core.actors.Exceptions$InternalState: null
    at reactivemongo.ConnectAll$IsMaster(828, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=140], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070373894>)
    at reactivemongo.IsMaster(828, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=142], auth=Set() }}(<time:1530070373894>)
    at reactivemongo.RefreshAll({{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=142], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070373754>)
    at reactivemongo.ConnectAll({{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=142], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070373754>)
    at reactivemongo.ConnectAll$IsMaster(827, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=142], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070363895>)
    at reactivemongo.IsMaster(827, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=141], auth=Set() }}(<time:1530070363895>)
    at reactivemongo.RefreshAll({{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=141], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070363753>)
    at reactivemongo.ConnectAll({{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=141], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070363753>)
    at reactivemongo.ConnectAll$IsMaster(826, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=141], auth=Set() }})(<time:1530070353894>)
    at reactivemongo.IsMaster(826, {{NodeSet None Node[ds249005.mlab.com:49005: Primary (10/10 available connections), latency=141], auth=Set() }}(<time:1530070353894>)
```

Comment: A large number of retries value is what helping me right now

Comment: Note that even if connected, there were `authenticated:0` so channel not usable due to prior autg issue

Comment: @cchantep when i restart the server everything come back to place? So by authentication issue what issue you think might be there?

Comment: It's quite impossible to say without a reproducer

Comment: @cchantep but can you tell me if there is a way to listen connection health of reactive mongo?

Comment: `authenticated:0, connected:10, channels:10` means that all channels were established/connected by not auth'ed, rather than network issue ...

Comment: @cchantep So, basically you mean it's the database server which is rejecting the connection after certain time and causing the subsequent problems in further re-tries?

Comment: I mean the credentials were "just" wrong, so even if the channels are ok it cannot work, for whatever reason by time of the issue

Comment: @cchantep But I am pretty sure that credentials are OK, because with same config, if I restart it gets connected!

Comment: And I'm pretty sure there was an auth error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174447/discussion-between-ravinder-payal-and-cchantep).